# Unable to set bottom margin in Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a `ListView` in an activity. In this `ListView` I am calling another `xml` file to set text properties and add an arrow image. With only `TextView`, I am able to set top and bottom margin of the `ListView` row but when I add arrow image, the bottom margin doesn't set but top margin works properly. Please let me know, where I am doing wrong. Here's my code of xml file below :

**list_text_black.xml** file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:maxWidth="30dp"  
            android:maxHeight="30dp"  
            android:src="@drawable/arrow1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="sdfjijogbvfbghgggg"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_weight="1.32" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this this may help you,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="Just Test"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: akash, i appreciate yor efforts can you please add explanation, whats different you are doing. it will help others too

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting what you want then this may help. use `android:paddingBottom = "12dp"` in `<ImageView>..<ImageView/>`

Comment: use `android:gravity="center"` in list View

Comment: sorry...i cant add images...need 10+ reputation.. :(

Comment: yess...many times...!!! this problem occurs only when i add image...otherwise works fine

Comment: thnxx jaimin for help... :)